# How do I make speech recognition work on flutter web

Tags: flutter, speech-recognition, flutter-web, webkitspeechrecognition

I am using flutter to build a speech recognition app that works on ios and android but it's not working on the web. So I decided to add an app.js file to the web folder so I can use it in my dart file. Am able to get other functions in this file to work but whenever I call the function that's supposed to make the speech recognition for web work it doesn't work and I get some error message in the console.
Here is the code in the `app.js` file:

```
let container = document.createElement('div');
let paragraph = document.createElement('p');
container.appendChild(paragraph);
document.body.appendChild(container);

window.SpeechRecognition = webkitSpeechRecognition || window.SpeechRecognition;
const synth = window.speechSynthesis;
recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.interimResults = true;

function speak(action) {
    const utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(action);
    synth.speak(utterThis);
  };

function dictate() {
    recognition.start();
    recognition.onresult = (event) => {
        console.log(event);
        const speechToText = event.results[0][0].transcript;
        console.log(speechToText);
        paragraph.textContent = speechToText;
        
        if (event.results[0].isFinal) {
            paragraph = document.createElement('p');
            container.appendChild(paragraph);

            speak('You are welcomed');
        }
    };
    };

window.logger = (flutter_value) => {
   console.log({ js_context: this, flutter_value });
}
```

In my `main.dart` file I used the `import 'dart:js' as js;` so that I can call the function like this

```
void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      js.context
          .callMethod('dictate');
    });
  }
```

When I call other function like this it works fine but when I call the dictate function it doesn't work and I get this message in the console:

```
404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
js_primitives.dart:32 ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
js_primitives.dart:32 The following DomException object was thrown while handling a gesture:
js_primitives.dart:32   InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'start' on 'SpeechRecognition': recognition has already
js_primitives.dart:32 started.
js_primitives.dart:32 
js_primitives.dart:32 When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
js_primitives.dart:32 app.js 28:17                                                                                                                                                           dictate
js_primitives.dart:32 package:build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler/C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/lib/js/dart2js/js_dart2js.dart 258:53  callMethod
js_primitives.dart:32 package:flutter_js/main.dart 50:12                                                                                                                                     <fn>
js_primitives.dart:32 package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 1148:30                                                                                                                     setState
js_primitives.dart:32 package:flutter_js/main.dart 48:5                                                                                                                                      [_incrementCounter]
js_primitives.dart:32 package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart 706:14                                                                                                                      [_handleTap]
js_primitives.dart:32 package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart 789:36                                                                                                                      <fn>
js_primitives.dart:32 package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 182:24                                                                                                                    invokeCallback
js_primitives.dart:32 package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 486:47                                                                                                                           handleTapUp
js_primitives.dart:32 package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 264:5                                                                                                                            [_checkUp]
js_primitives.dart:32 package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 236:7                                                                                                                            acceptGesture
js_primitives.dart:32 package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart 156:12                                                                                                                         sweep
js_primitives.dart:32 package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 222:20                                                                                                                       handleEvent
js_primitives.dart:32 package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 198:14                                                                                                                       dispatchEvent
js_primitives.dart:32 package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 156:7                                                                                                                        [_handlePointerEvent]
js_primitives.dart:32 package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 102:7                                                                                                                        [_flushPointerEventQueue]
js_primitives.dart:32 package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 86:32                                                                                                                        [_handlePointerDataPacket]
js_primitives.dart:32 package:build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler/C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 83:15                [_onPointerData]
js_primitives.dart:32 package:build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler/C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 334:7                <fn>
js_primitives.dart:32 package:build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler/C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 183:16
```

Is there something am getting wrong or what alternatives do I have to get the speech recognition working for the flutter web. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's unclear about the issue? It's something with calling `start`. It's an error specific to your speech recognition library.

Comment: How do you mean? where am I to call `start ` and what's the error specific to my speech library?

Comment: The error says "InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'start' on 'SpeechRecognition': recognition has already started." I can't really help you with that as it's an error related to your speech recognition library. Might help to look up that error specifically for that library to see if you misused the `start` function in some way.

Comment: Maybe try calling `stop` right before your `start` call?

Comment: I did and it worked. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Whatever this question asked for (2 years ago), it is not true now.

I just added speech-to-text functionality to my app, using [speech_to_text](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text)   package and it works in Chrome without any special efforts.

Comment: I am using it, it works fine when i am debugging, but it doesn't work when I deploy the application.